# Simple way to make comma separated list of DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-core

There is pattern I used a lot of in ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
(string.Join("<br>", someList.Select(item => Html.DisplayFor(model => item)))
```

But in ASP.NET Core DisplayFor(..) now returns `IHtmlContent`, and `IHtmlContent.ToString()` now returns literaly `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewBuffer"`, not a rendered content.

1. Which pattern should I use to fix code with minimal changes?
2. Which pattern is an idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried?: `(string.Join("<br>", someList.Select(item => Html.Raw(item)))`

Comment: @hujtomi , `Html.Raw` returns IHtmlContent, as DisplayFor do. There will be more of same

Comment: I just tried it and it seems like it works with `Html.Raw` I also tested with `(string.Join("<br>", someList))` and it also works if `someList` is a `string[]`

Comment: In case anyone is trying to do this with links, I found something that works: `@Html.Raw(string.Join("<br />", someList.Select(item => $"<a href='{item.Url}'>{item.Name}</a>")))`